# Why does it throw an Unhandled Exception here?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I'm trying to persist my calendar data with hive but when I start the program, it throws this:

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in type cast

This is my model class:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Event extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  late String title;

  @HiveField(1)
  late DateTime eventDateTime;

  @HiveField(2)
  bool wholeDayEvent;

  Event({
    required this.title,
    required this.eventDateTime,
    required this.wholeDayEvent,
  });

  @override
  String toString() => title;
}
```

And here's the build method of my displaying widget:

```
Expanded(
              child: ValueListenableBuilder<Box<Event>>(
                valueListenable: Boxes.getEvents().listenable(),
                builder: (context, box, _) {
                  final events = box.values.toList().cast<Event>();
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: events.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 12.0,
                          vertical: 4.0,
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          onTap: () => print('${box.values}'),
                          title: Text('${box.values}'),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that you changed some fields in your `Event` object, while your `Hive` database is not empty, so the previously stored objects do not have those new fields so their values are `null`, which throws the error.

You can  fix this by simply clearing your `Hive` box before using it, so it deletes the previous data objects and work with the new one, in your `main()`:

```
await Hive.openBox<Event>("yourBoxName"); // opens the box
await Hive.box<Event>("yourBoxName").clear(); // clear the box
```

Now you will have an empty box, and your code will work fine again.

you should just clear it one time to remove previous data, after that you could remove the `clear()` line and work normally.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is completely right. I did add a field with a boolean. Strangely the problem persists even after I clear the box as you suggested.
I also deleted the 'event.g.dart' file and auto-generated a new one but it doesn't help.

Comment: didn't you forget also to generate the new adapter for that new updated object  ?

Comment: was it the issue ?

Comment: That's what I did, right? I deleted that '.g.dart' file and run the command:
flutter packages pub run build_runner build...
I don't have to change anything with the registration of the related adapter, do I?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. The Error message still appears. Though, one line below the message it says:
#0      EventAdapter.read

Comment: yes you don't need to change it just running the command

Comment: I'm confused now, didn't you changed a field data type in your Event class without changing the HiveField number Id ?

Comment: Do you think changing the typeId of the corresponding HiveType would do anything?

Comment: Yes, I did. So I have to give the hive class a new typeId!